# Does word2vec supports multiple languages?

Tags: word2vec

I want to know if we can use word2vec algorithm to train models for languages other than English like Spanish, Chinese,Italian ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes! In fact one of Google's original word2vec papers highlighted its potential for use in machine-translation between language pairs:

*[Exploiting Similarities among Languages for Machine Translation](https://arxiv.org/abs/1309.4168)*

Note that as with English, you'll need to break example texts into word-tokens before feeding them to the Word2Vec algorithm, which may be harder in some languages.

Answer (score 1):

If like me you need to work with data that contains a mix of languages, you may be interested in my package that helps you translate word vectors between languages: [transvec](https://pypi.org/project/transvec/).

Bear in mind that while you can use Word2Vec on any language, there are no pre-trained models (that I'm aware of) that have been trained on multiple languages. Unless the mixed-language corpora also included information about translations between the languages, they probably wouldn't be of much use anyway.

`transvec` solves this problem by allowing you to convert word vectors between models, so you can use one model for each language and use `transvec` to find out which words in language A (the *target* language) are most similar to a word from language B (the *source* language). If you're interested in how this works, check out the README for the Python package or the [original research paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1309.4168.pdf) (which I just realised is the same paper from @gojomo's answer!) that describes the technique in more detail.

Here's a small example that shows how you can compare Russian word vectors to English word vectors in a meaningful way:

```
import gensim.downloader
from transvec.transformers import TranslationWordVectorizer

# Pretrained models in two different languages.
ru_model = gensim.downloader.load("word2vec-ruscorpora-300")
en_model = gensim.downloader.load("glove-wiki-gigaword-300")

# Training data: pairs of English words with their Russian translations.
# The more you can provide, the better.
train = [
    ("king", "царь_NOUN"), ("tsar", "царь_NOUN"),
    ("man", "мужчина_NOUN"), ("woman", "женщина_NOUN")
]

bilingual_model = TranslationWordVectorizer(en_model, ru_model).fit(train)

# Find words with similar meanings across both languages.
bilingual_model.similar_by_word("царица_NOUN", 1) # "queen"
# [('king', 0.7763221263885498)]
```

Don't worry about the weird POS tags on the Russian words - this is just a quirk of the particular pre-trained model I used.

So basically, if you can provide a list of words with their translations, then you can train a `TranslationWordVectorizer` to translate *any* word that exists in your source language corpus into the target language. When I used this for real, I produced some training data by extracting all the individual Russian words from my data, running them through Google Translate and then keeping everything that translated to a single word in English. The results were pretty good (sorry I don't have any more detail for the benchmark yet; it's still a work in progress!).